# Play Store: Beta test & Production APK different certificates

Tags: android, google-play

I started a beta test for an app in the Play Store, but I probably want to use another certificate for the production ('real' release) APK without changing the package name.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just tested it, it isn't possible, not even Alpha- and Beta-Test APKs can't have different certificates.

Comment: Was this the case going from beta to production? I've signed my Alpha/Beta apps with a test keystore and want to use my production key for the full release. Can you confirm from your experience this isn't possible please?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. You need to use the same keystore for your production apk that you used for the beta apks.

Comment: I came across the same issue. In real world how do we release different setup for alpha, beta and prod users?

Comment: Pain in the ass. Makes it really hard to work with outside contractors who need to test in-app purchase stuff.

I guess they do it so that an Alpha/Beta build can be pushed to Prod without re-exporting/re-uploading :(

Answer (score -2):

It might be possible as suggested on developer support site:

> Through alpha- and beta-testing functionality, Google Play Developer
>   Console lets you test two different versions of your app at the same
>   time in addition to your production version. Here’s how:
>
> Select an APK for your alpha or beta test. Select the group of users
>   for each test. Publish your alpha- or beta-test APK. Ask your testers
>   to opt in. Alpha- or beta-test apps will only appear in Google Play
>   for testers that opt-in and not to any other users. A production APK
>   is not required to publish an alpha- or beta-test app. It may take up
>   to 24 hours after publishing for the test link to become active.

Comment: The question was specifically about signing the app with different certificates, not just having two versions of an app in different stages of development in the alpha/beta/prod channels in the Play Store as you describe here.