# Play Store: Alpha test & Production APK different certificates

Tags: android, google-play

I started a alpha test for an app in the Play Store, but I probably want to use another certificate for the production ('real' release) APK without changing the package name.

Is this possible?

I know similar question is answered here [Play Store: Beta test & Production APK different certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489482/play-store-beta-test-production-apk-different-certificates) But here they have answered from beta to production and alpha and beta. So I am confused, whether my suggestion is possible. Thanks in advance