# How to sign contractors alpha build with debug.keystore?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, keystore, android-keystore

My contractor is working on my Android Apps Google API in-app purchase feature and I dont want to send them the actual distribution keystore. Can I have them sign it with the debug keystore somehow and upload to Alpha? (its not obvious how to do this in AS or in Google's documentation - and if thats even going to work for Alpha distribution)

Id like to avoid compiling and testing each version the build myself because the contractor and I have a 12hr time difference and I work my main job during the day.

Alternatively maybe there are other ways of dealing with this all together when working in AndroidStudio/GooglePlay with foreign contractors?

Thanks

Comment: does your contractor have your credentials to upload the APK to google play? just asking because even if you solve this signing problem, it's somehow strange for he or she to have your credentials

Comment: You can grant upload permissions to specific @gmail accounts for Alpha, Beta, and/or Prod. I have given them access to Alpha

Comment: you'll have to sign the APK yourself. See accepted answer and comments http://stackoverflow.com/q/18489482/2657100

Comment: Thanks thats clear. Sad there is not an easier way to work with contractors :(